# CSS for creating a baloon as a hint

Tags: css, layout, css-position

I'm tryng to create a baloon as a hint on top of the word in text. The text inside the baloon would have some block layout, so I need to put this layout into a rectangular block and display it relative to the word of interest. I'm trying to define CSS styles for the internals of the baloon, but so far that doesn't work.

Here is an example of the text:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="needs_hint">amet<span class="baloon">hint</span></span>, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

The word "amet" is the one I need the hint for, and I wrap it with an inline `span`. The staff needed for the hint is extracted into a nested `span`.

After applying the CSS below I have a hint floating on top of the word "amet", and that is expected and desired:

```css
.needs_hint {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.baloon {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: -50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Now I need to add text with more complex layout into the baloon. I'm replacing the word "hint" with a more complex html that contains a `<div>`:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="needs_hint">amet<span class="baloon">inline hint<div class="hint">inline-block hint</div></span></span>, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

I'm defining the CSS for this `<div>` line that:

```css
.hint {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This however extracts the "inline hint" inside the baloon, but leaves the "inline-block hint" part inside the text. What CSS would allow me to display some block html with divs, tables, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an *ad hoc* solution to my problem here: [How to create a pure CSS tooltip with HTML content for inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531029/how-to-create-a-pure-css-tooltip-with-html-content-for-inline-elements).

The inner `<span>` has to be replaced with a `<button>`, as this is the only inline element that allows to contain block elements.

The solution is quite unusual and surprising to me, as `<button>` has very different semantics, so other solutions are welcome. I would also like to hear the justification for this usage of the button tag.